# How can programatically we know "Automatically check for updates" is enabled using objective c in Mac OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos

To Keep the OSX and apps from the App store up to date, We always need to enable  "Automatically check for updates" in Preferences.

How can programatically we know "Automatically check for updates" is enabled ?